# slack edit message shortcut

Tags: shortcuts, slack

In slack the "edit last message" shortcut is supposed to be <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow). When I hit it the last message is populated in the message field, but when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after editing it shows up as a new message and the original message stays unedited.

Any idea on how to fix that?
Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that